# Dummy variable creation for each subcategory using tidyverse package

Tags: r, tidyverse, dummy-variable

I have a tibble(taken ref. from [How to create dummy variables per group of another variable in tidyverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56787088/how-to-create-dummy-variables-per-group-of-another-variable-in-tidyverse))

```
library(tidyverse)

input_data <- tribble( ~Subcat, ~Date, ~COMM1,~COMM2,~UOM,~AUC_TYPE,
                        #--|----------|-----|-----|----|----------------|
                        1, 2017-03-07, 40750,41400,"MT","English",
                        1, 2017-03-15, 40750,40000,"MT","English",

                        2, 2017-10-16, 41000,40500,"METER","Yankee",
                        2, 2017-11-06, 41010,40510,"METER","Yankee",
                        2, 2019-01-26, 50010,50510,"METER","English",

                        3, 2017-03-07, 40750,41400,"MT","English",
                        3, 2018-05-26, 50010,50510,"MT","English",
                        3, 2019-01-21, 40750,40200,"MT","English",
                        3, 2019-01-21, 40750,40200,"MT","English",

                        4, 2017-11-08, 37500,39000,"LTR","Dynamic Sealbid",
                        4, 2017-11-08, 37500,39000,"LTR","Dynamic Sealbid",
)
```

#### Desired output

```
output_data <- tribble( ~Subcat, ~Date, ~COMM1, ~COMM2, ~UOM_MT, ~UOM_METER ,~UOM_LTR, ~AUC_TYPE_English, ~`AUC_TYPE_Dynamic Sealbid`, ~AUC_TYPE_Yankee,
                        #--|----------|-----|-----|-|-|-|-|-|-|
                        1, 2017-03-07, 40750,41400,1,0,0,1,0,0,
                        1, 2017-03-15, 40750,40000,1,0,0,1,0,0,

                        2, 2017-10-16, 41000,40500,0,1,0,0,0,1,
                        2, 2017-11-06, 41010,40510,0,1,0,0,0,1,
                        2, 2019-01-26, 50010,50510,0,1,0,1,0,0,

                        3, 2017-03-07, 40750,41400,1,0,0,1,0,0,
                        3, 2018-05-26, 50010,50510,1,0,0,1,0,0,
                        3, 2019-01-21, 40750,40200,1,0,0,1,0,0,
                        3, 2019-01-21, 40750,40200,1,0,0,1,0,0,

                        4, 2017-11-08, 37500,39000,0,0,1,0,1,0,
                        4, 2017-11-08, 37500,39000,0,0,1,0,1,0,
)
```

Comment: Although there has been an accepted answer, you can still take mine as reference. It use a different concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

input_data %>%
   #Get unique row number
   mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
   #Get data in long format
   pivot_longer(cols = c(UOM, AUC_TYPE)) %>%
   #Combine columns
   unite(col, name, value) %>%
   #Get data in wide format
   pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = col, values_fn = list(col = ~1), 
               values_fill = list(col = 0)) %>%
   #Remove row column
   select(-row)


# A tibble: 11 x 10
#   Subcat  Date COMM1 COMM2 UOM_MT AUC_TYPE_English UOM_METER AUC_TYPE_Yankee UOM_LTR `AUC_TYPE_Dynamic Sealbid`
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>            <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>   <dbl>                      <dbl>
# 1      1  2007 40750 41400      1                1         0               0       0                          0
# 2      1  1999 40750 40000      1                1         0               0       0                          0
# 3      2  1991 41000 40500      0                0         1               1       0                          0
# 4      2  2000 41010 40510      0                0         1               1       0                          0
# 5      2  1992 50010 50510      0                1         1               0       0                          0
# 6      3  2007 40750 41400      1                1         0               0       0                          0
# 7      3  1987 50010 50510      1                1         0               0       0                          0
# 8      3  1997 40750 40200      1                1         0               0       0                          0
# 9      3  1997 40750 40200      1                1         0               0       0                          0
#10      4  1998 37500 39000      0                0         0               0       1                          1
#11      4  1998 37500 39000      0                0         0               0       1                          1
```

Comment: Your outcome is different from the OP's desired one. You don't use correct unique identifiers.

Comment: @DarrenTsai Can you tell me specifically which row's output doesn't match with that of OP? Note that column order in my output and OP's is different.

Answer (score 0):

This method uses `C()` and `contrasts()` to set the **contrast matrix** of factor variables, and calls `model.matrix()` to transform these factor variables to dummies.

Note that if a factor variable has k levels, `model.matrix()` will create k-1 dummy variables by default. So here I adjust this property by `C()` and `contrasts()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df %>%
  select("UOM_" = UOM, "AUC_TYPE_" = AUC_TYPE) %>%  # select and rename
  mutate_all(as.factor) %>%
  mutate_all(~ C(., contrasts(., contrasts = F), how.many = n_distinct(.))) %>%
  model.matrix(~ ., data = .) %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  select(-`(Intercept)`) %>%
  bind_cols(select(df, -c(UOM, AUC_TYPE)), .)

# # A tibble: 11 x 10
#    Subcat  Date COMM1 COMM2 UOM_LTR UOM_METER UOM_MT `AUC_TYPE_Dynamic Sealbid` AUC_TYPE_English AUC_TYPE_Yankee
#     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>                      <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>
#  1      1  2007 40750 41400       0         0      1                          0                1               0
#  2      1  1999 40750 40000       0         0      1                          0                1               0
#  3      2  1991 41000 40500       0         1      0                          0                0               1
#  4      2  2000 41010 40510       0         1      0                          0                0               1
#  5      2  1992 50010 50510       0         1      0                          0                1               0
#  6      3  2007 40750 41400       0         0      1                          0                1               0
#  7      3  1987 50010 50510       0         0      1                          0                1               0
#  8      3  1997 40750 40200       0         0      1                          0                1               0
#  9      3  1997 40750 40200       0         0      1                          0                1               0
# 10      4  1998 37500 39000       1         0      0                          1                0               0
# 11      4  1998 37500 39000       1         0      0                          1                0               0
```